# Raphael SVG VML Implement Multi Pivot Points for Rotation

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation, raphael, trigonometry

Over the last two days I've effectively figured out how NOT to rotate Raphael Elements.

Basically I am trying to implement a multiple pivot points on element to rotate it by mouse.

When a user enters rotation mode 5 pivots are created. One for each corner of the bounding box and one in the center of the box.

When the mouse is down and moving it is simple enough to rotate around the pivot using Raphael [elements.rotate(degrees, x, y)](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#rotate) and calculating the degrees based on the mouse positions and atan2 to the pivot point.

The problem arises after I've rotated the element, bbox, and the other pivots. There x,y position in the same only there viewport is different.

In an SVG enabled browser I can create new pivot points based on [matrixTransformation and getCTM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#NestedTransformations). However after creating the first set of new pivots, every rotation after the pivots get further away from the transformed bbox due to rounding errors.

[image: rotate errors]

The above is not even an option in IE since in is VML based and cannot account for transformation.

> Is the only effective way to implement
>   element rotation is by using rotate
>   absolute or rotating around the center
>   of the bounding box?
>
> Is it possible at all the create multi
>   pivot points for an object and update
>   them after mouseup to remain in the
>   corners and center of the transformed
>   bbox?

***UPDATE:***
I've attempted to use jQuery offset to find the pivot after it's been rotated, and to use that offset location as the pivot point.

Demo site ...
http://weather.speedfetishperformance.com/dev/raphael/rotation.html

Comment: This looks to me like it might be easily fixable - that is, I think you may be closer to a proper solution than you think... could you post or upload your code somewhere?

Comment: Edited to show code ... this way of course is not IE friendly

Answer (score 1):

The best cross-browser way I can think of to do what you want is to implement the rotation yourself rather than let SVG do it. Rotating x,y coordinates is fairly simple and I've been using this (tcl) code whenever I need to do 2D rotation: [Canvas Rotation](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8595).

The upside to this is you have maximum control of the rotation since you're doing it manually. This solves the problems you're having trying to guess the final coordinates after rotation. Also, this should be cross browser compatible.

The downside is you have to use paths. So no rects (though it should be easy to convert them to paths) or ellipses (a little bit harder to convert to path but doable). Also, since you're doing it manually, it should be slower than letting SVG do it for you.

Here's a partial implementation of that Tcl code in javascript:

*first we need a regexp to tokenize SVG paths:*

```
var svg_path_regexp = (function(){
  var number = '-?[0-9.]+';
  var comma = '\s*[, \t]\s*';
  var space = '\s+';
  var xy = number + comma + number;
  var standard_paths = '[mlcsqt]';
  var horiz_vert = '[hv]\s*' + number;
  var arc = 'a\s*' + xy + space + number + space + xy + space + xy;
  var OR = '\s*|';

  return new RegExp(
    standard_paths +OR+
    xy +OR+
    horiz_vert +OR+
    arc,

    'ig'
  );
})();
```

*now we can implement the rotate function:*

```
function rotate_SVG_path (path, Ox, Oy, angle) {
  angle = angle * Math.atan(1) * 4 / 180.0; // degrees to radians

  var tokens = path.match(svg_path_regexp);

  for (var i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
    var token = tokens[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); // trim string

    if (token.match(/\d/)) { // assume it's a coordinate
      var xy = token.split(/[, \t]+/);
      var x = parseFloat(xy[0]);
      var y = parseFloat(xy[1]);
      x = x - Ox;  // Shift to origin
      y = y - Oy;
      var xx = x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle); // Rotate
      var yy = x * Math.sin(angle) + y * Math.cos(angle);
      x = xx + Ox; // Shift back
      y = yy + Oy;

      token = x + ',' + y;
    }
    else if (token.match(/^[hv]/)) {
      // handle horizontal/vertical line here
    }
    else if (token.match(/^a/)) {
      // handle arcs here
    }

    tokens[i] = token;
  }
  return tokens.join('');
}
```

The above rotate function implements everything except horizontal/vertical lines (you need to keep track of previous xy value) and arcs. Neither should be too hard to implement.

Comment: So this is the only way to achieve this pivot effect is to destroy and recreate the paths? Originally I was applying the rotation formula to a point to find its new origin. I then found out that the jQuery offset was nearly equivalent each time so I started using that. I am able to find the new points after rotation ... just seems like I'm missing a key piece of information about multiple revolutions. Just seems that there would be an easier way

Comment: You don't actually destroy the path object, that would be much slower. Instead modify the pathstring: `obj.attr('path',rotate(obj.attr('path'),x,y,angle))`

Comment: Actually, for cleaner code, you can even implement it as a method: `Raphael.el.rotate_path = function ...` then you can call it like: `obj.rotate_path(x,y,angle)`